# Hierarchy of pages

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a website will have two contact pages (one for each address).
Wanted to create a breadcrumbs structure like "Home > Contacts > 1 Shop" and "Home > Contacts > Shop 2", whose links would contact/store-1 and contacts/store-2.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create pages for each

Home
-Contacts
--1 Shop 
--Shop 2

Home is the parent to Contacts
 Contacts is the parent to both 1 Shop and Shop 2.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

Comment: yes, but I don't have a content to put in contacts page. And have a page with blank content is...